# DISTINCT Statement how to merge two rows from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Please give any solution how to merge two rows from one table then  how can use distinct

Query:

```
select distinct  uid , r_uid from messenger  where uid=213 or r_uid =213
```

I got output like this

```
      uid     r_uid
     --------------
      213     239
      239     213
     -----------------
```

But we need like this

```
           new id
        -----------
            239
         ---------
```

Plese   give me any solution  i am new in MySQL thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `union`:

```
select uid as new_id from messenger
where uid = 213  
union
select r_uid from messenger
where r_uid = 213;
```

Comment: Will return 213 as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the "other value.  The simplest way is likely to be:

```
select uid
from messenger
where r_uid = 213
union -- intentional, remove duplicates
select r_uid
from messenger
where uid = 213;
```

You can also do this using `case`:

```
select distinct (case when r_uid = 213 then uid else r_uid end)
from messenger
where 213 in (r_uid, uid);
```

Comment: @CforCode . . . As the OP, you can accept whichever answer you prefer.  I am curious, however, why you unaccepted this after more than a year.